# PHP: Calling a function in the argument of another function

Tags: php, function

What's the syntax of calling a function in another function in php? 
I want something like:

```
function argfunction($a,$b,$c){
}
function anotherfunction(argfunction($a,$b,$c), $d, $e)
{
}
```

I am not calling `argfunction` again in the definition of `anotherfunction`

Comment: Such syntax doesn't exist..... it's simply not permitted by the language..... what's it even supposed to do?

Comment: Use the output of a previously defined function as the input of another function-it is not allowed?

Comment: @shoestringfries When you call then function yes, but not as function definition. So do: `anotherfunction(argfunction($a,$b,$c), $d, $e)` and in your definition: `function anotherfunction($fresult, $d, $e)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters of a function should be declarative, i.e. they are not supposed to do something.

But you can do  this with the [`callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) keyword (PHP 5.4):

```
function argfunction($a,$b,$c){
    return $a+$b+$c;
}

function anotherfunction(callable $a_func, $a, $b, $c, $d, $e) {
    // call the function we are given:
    $abc = $a_func($a, $b, $c);
    return $abc + $d * $e;
}

// call:
anotherfunction ("argfunction", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // output: 26
```

Or you can pass the whole function definition:

```
echo anotherfunction (function ($a, $b, $c) {
        return $a+$b+$c; 
    }, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);  // output: 26
```

Or, assign a function to a variable, and pass that:

```
$myfunc = function ($a, $b, $c) {
    return $a+$b+$c; 
};
echo anotherfunction ($myfunc, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);  // output: 26
```

But if you just want to pass the result of a function call to another function, then it is much more straightforward:

```
function anotherfunction2($abc, $d, $e) {
    return $abc + $d * $e;
}

echo anotherfunction2 (argfunction(1, 2, 3), 4, 5); // output: 26
```

Comment: not sure if this is the right interpretation but you mean for function  `anotherfunction($abc, $d, $e)` you literally string the arguments of `argfunction` together? What should the format for `argfunction` be then if I call it within the function definition of `anotherfunction`?

Comment: No, in the call `anotherfunction2 (argfunction(1, 2, 3), 4, 5);`, PHP will first call *argfunction* with arguments *1,2,3*, which will return 6. Then PHP will call *anotherfunction2* passing it that previous result as the first argument, so the arguments passed are *6,4,5*. These are assigned to the variable *$abc* (what's in a name), *$d* and *$e* respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Does not make sense but I will assume that you are expressing your idea in a wrong way.

Would you maybe looking for something similar to callback? 
Take a look at the following: [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)